# Automatically apply PDF markup?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

Is there any LaTeX workflow (probably a python or perl program) that can read a marked-up Acrobat PDF file and apply the inserted and deleted characters?

It would really save me a lot of time on this big book that I got back from the copy editor.

For example, in the image below, I would like to remove the word `circulate` from the `.tex` file and insert the text between `without` and `permission`.

[image]

EDIT: I tried Acrobat's EXPORT AS DOCX feature and it picked up the insert as comments (but all of my fonts are screwed up). So perhaps if I can get Acrobat export to work properly, I can write some code in python to decode the edits to the DOCX file and apply them to the text?

Comment: I don't see a sensible workflow. There is nearly no connection between the tex and the pdf. Also such markups aren't connected to the text, they are simply annotation floating on the page.

Comment: There's also not a decent connection between the code of the pdf and where things appear in the page (eg, the code for the red line doesn't need to be anywhere near the code for "circulate"), which is why an accessible pdf is so difficult (in my understanding).